# How to cut lines exactly outline of shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, logo, designers

ish to illustrator, and I've been working on this logo for my partner. I have created all these lines and am happy with how it is looking.
However, I want the lines that make up the image to be cut the exact shape, rather than being behind a shape to make it appear as if they are. [image]
(as shown in the image) that is how I would like the end result to look, with most lines fitted to the shape and some sticking out. if someone is able to help me in how I would go about cutting the lines to achieve this? I would be very grateful!
[image]

Also another question is there a way to make the lines maintain there 'thickness' when increasing/decreasing size without changing the stroke?
[image]
n o t e: Im sorry of this seems like a really dumb question :( i'm struggling finding answers lmao.

Answer (score 10):

Select you letter shapes (you have already done Type> Create Outlines) and all the strokeed paths (lines).

Choose the Shapebuilder Tool.

Hold Alt/ Option as you drag through the lines you want to remove.

[image]

Comment: You might want to add that its important rhat you cut open lines if any of the lines form a loop illustrator opts to build closed shapes.

Comment: @kyle well illustrated. thumbsup.

Comment: Thank you soo much mate!!

Answer (score 0):

@Kyle explained beautifully.

There is another simpler method as well.
You can just select the nodes which are outside and press delete.
To answer your second question, I am not sure but I believe that you are doing "CTRL" and "+" to zoom in to the canvas, so the shape is not thickening, its just that the whole canvas is zoomed.

Hope that helped.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you soo much :)